# Handling DTOs across tables when one part of the object is an update while another is a create

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-core, dto

I am having an issue deciding how to handle DTOs for Entity Framework in the following scenario.

I have a customer table, and in a separate table I have the customer's contacts. My problem comes from the fact that a customer can initially be created without any contacts. So an update (HTTP PUT) may update an existing customer by adding a new contact. Or it may update an existing customer bt updating an existing contact. In the latter case, my contact object in the DTO will need an ID. In the former case it won't.

```
public class UpdateCustomer {
  int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
}
```

A contact DTO may look like this:

```
public class Contact {
  <Will need contactID on update>
  public CustomerId {get; set; }
  public string ContactType {get; set;}
  public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
}
```

This works great when a user wants to create a customer and create contacts at the same time using a post. No contact objects need IDs. But let's say they create a customer with one contact. Now they want to update that customer, update the existing contact, but also add a new contact. This will still be a call to the Put method, but one Contact in the list will need an ID, the other won't.

I see a couple ways to solve this. The most obvious is separate customer creation/updates and contact creation/updates into separate requests. Now I can have a separate objects for each, one with an ID, one without. This is what I am leaning towards, and the client side app would just have to make two separate API calls.

The other option is to include an ID in the Contact object on the server side regardless. If the client app doesn't supply a contact ID, it will be null. If I see it's null I can attempt an add, if it's not null I can attempt an update.

I like the first idea because it keeps thinks separate, but results in extra API calls. I like the second because it allows one API call to update all components associated with a customer at once. The drawback is I may assume the end user wants an add when they really want an update if they leave off an ID.

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm just looking for suggestions or feedback.

Update: Using Roar's suggestion this is my working solution below. Note that I referred to the class as customer in my original post but that's actually Client in my DB. I just found it to be confusing using Client in a post about a web api.

```
   public async Task UpdateClient(Dtos.Shared.Client client)
    {
        if (!ClientExists(client.ClientId))
        {
            throw new ClientNotFoundException();
        }

        Client clientToUpdate = await AdministrativeContext.ListClients()
            .Where(c => c.ClientUuid == client.ClientId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        clientToUpdate.ClientName = client.ClientName;
        //filter existing db elements that are still in DTO as well
        clientToUpdate.Contacts = clientToUpdate.Contacts
            .Where(c => client.Contacts.Any(con => con.ContactId == c.ContactUuid))
            .ToList();

        client.Contacts.ToList().ForEach(async contact =>
        {
            if (contact.ContactId == null || contact.ContactId == Guid.Empty) //if guid missing, we want to add
            {
                clientToUpdate.Contacts.Add(new Entities.Contact()
                {
                    ClientId = await AdministrativeContext.GetClientKeyFromGuidAsync(client.ClientId),
                    ContactUuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                    LastName = contact.LastName,
                    Address = contact.Address,
                    Email = contact.Email,
                    Phone = contact.Phone,
                    TypeId = (await AdministrativeContext.ContactTypes.Where(ct => ct.ContactTypeName == contact.ContactType).FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ContactTypeId
                });
            }
            else //guid defined means update
            {
                Contact existingContact = clientToUpdate.Contacts.Where(c => contact.ContactId == c.ContactUuid).FirstOrDefault();

                existingContact.ClientId = await AdministrativeContext.GetClientKeyFromGuidAsync(client.ClientId);
                existingContact.Address = contact.Address;
                existingContact.Email = contact.Email;
                existingContact.FirstName = contact.FirstName;
                existingContact.LastName = contact.LastName;
                existingContact.Phone = contact.Phone;
                existingContact.TypeId = (await AdministrativeContext.ContactTypes
                    .Where(ct => ct.ContactTypeName == contact.ContactType)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ContactTypeId;
            }
        });

        await AdministrativeContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you have done the necessary analysis.  The two options you listed are viable.  Just a matter of which one will be easier in the long run for continued maintenance of your application.  If your users will be updating/adding contacts frequently then the first option seems to make more sense.  If this is just a one and done type deal, then the second option may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the update-case usually like this in a single request.

- Get Customer from db with contact collection populated
- Iterate through all contacts in customer db instance. If not present in customer DTO, then remove contact from contact collection in customer db instance
- Iterate through all contacts from DTO. If Contact#Id = 0 (or maybe null in this case), add a new contact to contact collection in customer db instance, else update existing contact instance in contact collection
- Update customer db instance with remaining data from DTO
- Save customer along with contact collection to db (requires cascading)

I'm usually working with NHibernate, but the principle should work with EF as well.

Pros:

- Simple, handles create, update and delete for contacts along with customer update
- Single db-call for update

Cons:

- Requires all contacts in payload on every update

Comment: I quite like this answer and here is why. I have a unique constraint on my contact table. That constraint is on customer and contact type. I have a billing contact type and a primary contact type. The problem is if a customer already has one of each and you want to change billing to primary and primary to billing, you can't. Changing one at a time with a single API call for each will result in a unique constraint violation every time and I will be unable to update. By passing the whole list as you do I believe this can be avoided.

Comment: Good news. Let's keep in touch if any problems.